# Parallel.For performance

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

This code is from Microsoft article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx, with small changes:

```
        const int size = 10000000;
        int[] nums = new int[size];
        Parallel.For(0, size, i => {nums[i] = 1;});
        long total = 0;

        Parallel.For<long>(
            0, size, () => 0,
            (j, loop, subtotal) =>
            {
                return subtotal + nums[j];
            },
            (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, x) 
        );

        if (total != size)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error");
        }
```

Non-parallel loop version is:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            total += nums[i];
        }
```

When I measure loop execution time using `StopWatch` class, I see that parallel version is slower by 10-20%. Testing is done on Windows 7 64 bit, Intel i5-2400 CPU, 4 cores, 4 GB RAM. Of course, in Release configuration.

In my real program I am trying to compute an image histogram, and parallel version runs 10 times slower. Can such kind of computation tasks, when every loop invocation is very fast, be successfully parallelized with TPL?

**Edit.**

Finally I managed to shave more that 50% of histogram calculation execution time with Parallel.For, when divided the whole image to some number of chunks. Every loop body invocation now handles the whole chunk, and not one pixel.

Comment: Also bear in mind that Parallel.For maximises the 64-bit. I have tested it in the past with a program where the Parallel.Loop delivered good performance (as explained in the answer below) and have noticed a notable improvement when targetting the project to x64. In that specific configuration, it was around 3-4 times faster (in the x86 version the Parallel.Loop was already 5 times faster than the normal loop).

Comment: Just to clarify the exact conditions in the case of my previous comment: iterative calculations/storage taking quite a long time. In its original version, it was taking around 1 hour; which was reduced to around 20 mins with the parallel loop on x86 and to 5 mins with the 64-bit-targetted version. For simpler configurations (loops taking just milliseconds), it is pretty difficult to improve appreciably the performance of a simple loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Parallel.For` should be used for things that are a little heacy, not to sum simple numbers! Just the use of the delegate `(j, loop, subtotal) =>` is probably more than enough to give 10-20% more time. And we aren't even speaking of the threading overhead. It would be interesting to see some benchmark against a delegate summer in the for cycle and to see not only the "real world" time, but the CPU time.

I have even added a comparison to a "simple" delegate that does the same thing as the `Parallel.For<>` delegate.

Mmmh... Now I have some numbers at 32 bits, on my PC (an AMD six core)

```
32 bits
Parallel: Ticks:      74581, Total ProcessTime:    2496016
Base    : Ticks:      90395, Total ProcessTime:     312002
Func    : Ticks:     147037, Total ProcessTime:     468003
```

The Parallel is a little faster at wall time, but 8x slower at processor time :-)

But at 64 bits:

```
64 bits
Parallel: Ticks:     104326, Total ProcessTime:    2652017
Base    : Ticks:      51664, Total ProcessTime:     156001
Func    : Ticks:      77861, Total ProcessTime:     312002
```

Modified code:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} bits", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? 32 : 64);

var cp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
cp.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

const int size = 10000000;
int[] nums = new int[size];
Parallel.For(0, size, i => { nums[i] = 1; });

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

long total = 0;

{
    TimeSpan start = cp.TotalProcessorTime;
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    Parallel.For<long>(
        0, size, () => 0,
        (j, loop, subtotal) =>
        {
            return subtotal + nums[j];
        },
        (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, x)
    );

    sw.Stop();
    TimeSpan end = cp.TotalProcessorTime;

    Console.WriteLine("Parallel: Ticks: {0,10}, Total ProcessTime: {1,10}", sw.ElapsedTicks, (end - start).Ticks);
}

if (total != size)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

total = 0;

{
    TimeSpan start = cp.TotalProcessorTime;
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        total += nums[i];
    }

    sw.Stop();
    TimeSpan end = cp.TotalProcessorTime;

    Console.WriteLine("Base    : Ticks: {0,10}, Total ProcessTime: {1,10}", sw.ElapsedTicks, (end - start).Ticks);
}

if (total != size)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

total = 0;

Func<int, int, long, long> adder = (j, loop, subtotal) =>
{
    return subtotal + nums[j];
};

{
    TimeSpan start = cp.TotalProcessorTime;
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        total = adder(i, 0, total);
    }

    sw.Stop();
    TimeSpan end = cp.TotalProcessorTime;

    Console.WriteLine("Func    : Ticks: {0,10}, Total ProcessTime: {1,10}", sw.ElapsedTicks, (end - start).Ticks);
}

if (total != size)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error");
}
```

Comment: So, TPL is not good enough for such kind of simple tasks. In native C++ I can use OpenMP. Is there anything in .NET, that fits such computation tasks?

Comment: @AlexFarber I have yet to find a good use for `Parallel.For<>` :-) The number of good use cases is very very small. Perhaps downloading multiple web pages...

Comment: @AlexFarber Multithreading is something "hard" for a PC. It works well when you have "long and parallelizable" things you want to do. You want to apply a filter on 10 images? Then 10 threads is perfect. Sadly rarely you have 10 images to Sharpen :-)

Comment: @AlexFarber Last thing.. I think `Parallel.For<>` is one of the things I call "antipatterns ready to use"... You see it, you use it, you do damage while thinking you are smart. Other (lesser) antipatterns ready to use are for example `.ToList().ForEach(p =>` and `AsQueryable()` (with persons that think that, like magic, it transforms the `IEnumerable<>` to a real query). `Parallel.For<>` is probably worse because if you use `Stopwatch` it *seems* to be faster. Sadly you are using 8x CPU resources :-)

Comment: just one comment to your last statement: there is nothing of sadly in using 8x more CPU resources; these resources are there and if you are not using them, you are not maximising the capabilities of the computer. I personally prefer to maximise the performance of each single bit and, for example, the project I referred in my comments above came from a different developer (there are situations taking hours, but this specific development was created in a pretty inefficient way) and was counting on the "Parallel.For boosting" what IMO is a really bad coding practice (out of space)

Comment: (out of space) but the reality was that this specific program (with its highly-inefficient loop) was taking the same in a 1-core computer than in an 8-core one. Thanks to Parallel.Loop, the 8-core over-power could be maximised and this is an option you always can take advantage of. I did quite a few performance tests with this application (as said, horribly built which had to be maximised no matter what) and can confirm that the high improvement in speed due to the parallel.loop wasn't affecting the behaviour of the computer. I mean... (out of space again)

Comment: (out of space)... From my perspective as user, my 8-core computer behaved identically by having the application running with a normal loop or with a Parallel.Loop. By looking at the CPU performance, in the second case, the 8 cores were used but not until reaching a point where I could notice it as user. Thus with the normal loop my computer was not adequately maximised to run this specific (, highly-inefficient) program. I hope that I let my point clear (sorry for the long comment :)).

Comment: @varocarbas As I said, there are specific use-cases for using `Parallel.For<>`. But they are few and far between. Computations that take hours are prime candidate. Everything else probably not. The problem is that how it's packaged, not what it does. It mustn't be a first-choice, it must be a last choice.

Comment: I fully agree with the statement "mustn't be a first-choice" which is every day less popular (mainly in certain "areas of expertise" and with the increasing power availability, for example via GPU, like CUDA). I just wanted to make the point completely clear by bringing my experience in this specific development into consideration.

Comment: @xanatos - the good news are that in histogram calculation I managed to shave more that 50% of execution time with Parallel.For, when divided the whole image to some number of chunks. Every loop body invocation now handles the whole chunk, and not one pixel.